# How to redirect port for React production

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, reactjs, express

I am trying to setup both *Express.js* and *React.js* apps on the same Ubuntu server. This is a VPS which runs **Plesk Onyx** where we have a lot of virtual hosts that run over port 80.

To run them continuosly I have installed and ran [forever](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-run-node-js-server-in-background/), then these apps starts on ports `3000`and `5000` (for instance).

I executed commands:

```
forever start -c "node src/server" ./ -l ./express.log
forever start -c "npm start" ./ -l ./react.log
```

Neither of the log files saves nothing, but that is not the point. Both are running as in the previous commands line but in those ports.

How do I redirect at least React port to 80 for this only app? Usually with PHP should work `.htaccess` but I am not sure for Nodejs.

Edit: The form code which sends from the React app through Express (worked great with React.js before building with `npm run build`:

The React component:

```
sendEmail(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    (async () => {
        let response = await fetch(
            `${window.location.origin}/contacto`,
            options
        );
        let data = await response.json();

        if (!data.success) {
            this.setState(
                Object.assign(this.state, {
                    error: true,
                    texto: { error: <p>{data.message}</p> },
                    alert: {
                        visible: true,
                        tipo: "alert-danger"
                    }
                })
            );
        } else {
            this.setState(
                Object.assign(this.state, {
                    error: false,
                    texto: { error: <p>{data.message}</p> },
                    alert: {
                        visible: true,
                        tipo: "alert-success"
                    }
                })
            );
            document.getElementById("formulario-contacto").reset();
        }
    })();
}
```

The Express stuff:

```
// Static site init
server.use("/", express.static("build"));

server.post("/contacto", (req, res) => {
  try {
    server.mailer.send(
      "email",
      {
        to: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
        subject: `Contacto ${req.body.asunto}`,
        body: req.body
      },
      err => {
        if (err) {
          res.send({ success: false, message: err });
        } else {
          res.send({ success: true, message: "Mensaje enviado" });
        }
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    res.send({ success: false, message: err });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might want to change how you're going about this. You should consider building your React app into static output that you then serve with your Express.js app/server.

Assuming you are using create-react-app you can run the "build" command to create your static files. Then set your Express.js app to serve it. See [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) for details on serving static files and [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment) for building static files for your react app.

Alternatively you can also use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [parcel](https://parceljs.org/) to build out your react app if you didn't use creat-react-app.

For getting express on port 80 you can set your port variable to 80 or directly set it in the app.listen() function `app.listen(80)`

Comment: Sorry, I was running the wrong script. It worked pretty much but now I am getting a blank screen when sending a form with [this error](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=31&args[]=object%20with%20keys%20%7Bname%2C%20data%2C%20stage%7D&args[]=)

Comment: How are you sending the form, does a route in your express app handle it? If you have code you can share it'll be easier to help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the url yourself? Them template string might not be passing it correctly from the window object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand the question, but since you're using express, you will have an `app.listen(3000)` call somewhere in your index.js.

You can change that to 3000 or 80 depending on the value of `process.env.NODE_ENV` which will be set to either 'production', 'development' or 'none'.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using CRA from the facebook.
You can create an .env file at the root folder of the project 
and specify in it `PORT=80`